# Sqldeveloper gives error on running using java on Fedora

Tags: java

I'm tired to install sqldeveloper (sqldeveloper-4.1.0.17.29-1.noarch.rpm)
on Fedora OS so I installed jdk successfully and installed sqldevelover successfully too then I started the sqldevelober from terminal and it ask for the directory for the jdk I set the directory and then I got the error I tried to Uninstall the sqldeveloper and install it again and the same error coming up so please help I will attach the screens of the processes:

1-cheching that the java and sqldeveloper installed

> [root@alaadin-fedora RPMS]# yum list java-1*
>   Loaded plugins: langpacks
>   Installed Packages
>   java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64                                1:1.8.0.31-3.b13.fc21                   @updates
>   java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64                       1:1.8.0.31-3.b13.fc21                   @updates
>   Available Packages
>   java-1.8.0-openjdk.i686                                  1:1.8.0.31-3.b13.fc21                   updates 
>   java-1.8.0-openjdk-accessibility.x86_64                  1:1.8.0.31-3.b13.fc21                   updates 
>   java-1.8.0-openjdk-demo.x86_64                           1:1.8.0.31-3.b13.fc21                   updates 
>   java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.i686                            1:1.8.0.31-3.b13.fc21                   updates 
>   java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64                          1:1.8.0.31-3.b13.fc21                   updates 
>   java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.i686                         1:1.8.0.31-3.b13.fc21                   updates 
>   java-1.8.0-openjdk-javadoc.noarch                        1:1.8.0.31-3.b13.fc21                   updates 
>   java-1.8.0-openjdk-src.x86_64                            1:1.8.0.31-3.b13.fc21                   updates 
>   [root@alaadin-fedora RPMS]# rpm -q sql*
>   package sqldeveloper-4.1.0.17.29-1.noarch.rpm is not installed

2-after I gave it the pass of the jdk and when I run sqldeveloper it gives me that error:

> [root@alaadin-fedora RPMS]# sqldeveloper
>
> Oracle SQL Developer
>    Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/dbtools/raptor/startup/HomeSupport : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:363)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
>       at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.LauncherUtil.processOJStartupHook(LauncherUtil.java:356)
>       at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.LauncherUtil.initialize(LauncherUtil.java:101)
>       at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.OracleIdeLauncher.main(OracleIdeLauncher.java:80)

as I said I tired to re install sqldeveloper and it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the installed java version with the minimum java runtime version specified for sql developer. It seems like the required version is higher that the installed version.

Comment: But you can see from his yum output he has JDK 8 installed, which matches major version 52.

Comment: Rup is right and also please give me the commands or the hits to check what you think of the problem and thanks for the fast replay